# different background images for different pages loaded using div tag

Tags: html, css

i am working on multipage application by loading mainpage.html into index.html by using  tag i need background image different one for different html pages such as mainpage,page1,page2 etc.can any one help ??

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>wsdl Demo</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
        <script>window.$ = window.jQuery = WLJQ;</script>
    </head>
    <body style="display: none;">
        <!-- This is static header, it will be shown always -->
        <div id="header">
            <h1>WS DEMO</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="wrapper">
            <!-- This is a placeholder for dynamic page content -->
            <div id="pagePort"></div>
        </div>

        <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
        <script src="js/main.js"></script>
        <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
function wlCommonInit(){
 busyIndicator = new WL.BusyIndicator();

 // Special case for Windows Phone 8 only.
 if (WL.Client.getEnvironment() == WL.Environment.WINDOWS_PHONE_8) {
     path = "/www/default/";
 }
 
 $("#pagePort").load(path + "pages/MainPage.html", function(){
  $.getScript(path + "js/MainPage.js", function() {
   if (currentPage.init) {
    currentPage.init();
   }
  });
 });
}
```

```css
body{
  background: red; 
} 

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false -->
```

```html
//mainpage.html

<script>
 $.getScript(path + "js/MainPage.js");
</script>

<p id="currentPage"></p>

<div class="container">
<label>username</label> <input type="text" id="username"><br><br>
<label>password</label> <input type="text" id="userpwd"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="login" class="appButton" onclick="validate();">
</div>
<p id="mytable"></p>
```

Comment: Instead of trying to post multipage demo snippet here, you can use http://Plnkr.co

Comment: will look on that next time @manoj any solution for my problem above

Comment: In each of your files, you can have different classes for the body and then use below CSS `.index {
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/sports');
}

.mainpage {
  background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/1200/1200/nature');
}`

Comment: <body><div=pageport></body> i am loading 2nd page into pageport.by using body tag on 2nd page it have 2 body tags right whether it works ???

Comment: Sorry but that doesn't allow us to see your problem. Please use http://Plnkr.co and post the link.

Comment: Personally, I use the method of adding classes to the body element... `<body class="index"></body>` then in CSS `body.index {background-image: url('link/to/img');}`. IDK if this actually does what you need, but from my interpretation of your post I believe it should.

Comment: The solution posted by @Dendromaniac would be best for the OP to use.

Comment: i tried that too but not working

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want a different background image applied to the body element but you only have control of a fragment of the page, a `style` element should work - you might need `!important` to override the default:

```
<div id="pageport">
    <style>
        body { background-image: url('images/newbg.jpg') !important; }
    </style>
</div>
```

Comment: It's hard to know the best way to do this without seeing what the page currently does, i.e. how the current background image is set. Is it set in main.css? Or MainPage.js? Or some other way? I might suggest using `script` instead of `style` but if mainpage.html is loaded via AJAX most modern browsers will probably refuse to execute any script contained within. Can you modify currentPage.init()?

Answer (score 0):

In connection with the comment I made I have decided to post my solution as an answer. My solution is rather simple, add a class to the body tag and then change the background using an external CSS file - based on the classes used.

e.g:

```
...
<body class="index">
...

//in the CSS:

body.index {
  background: #F00;
}
```

Then simply in each of the different HTML pages, change the class of the body tag to suite the background you want.

Check [this Plunk](http://plnkr.co/3IytxX8KsJ8f7i19x6LX) for live example

If you need any clarification, drop a comment and I'll get back to ya!